# Why isn't the current directory in sys.path for a django application

Tags: python, django

To my understanding, the `sys.path` has the current directory (the directory the module is in) as its first index, yet this seems inconsistent with django.

I have a project structure:

[image]

In `my_file_1.py`, printing `sys.path` gives me:
[image]

In `my_file_2.py`, printing `sys.path` gives me:
[image]

These two sys.path prints makes sense since that red underline is the directory the modules are in (their respective current directory).

However, in my django app with the following project structure:

[image]

When printing sys.path in urls.py, I get:

[image]

Which is the root directory of the project, instead of the current directory of urls.py which should be `c:\\Users\\5403\\Desktop\\tutorial\\tutorial`

Could someone explain this inconsistency and correct me if I have any misconceptions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django modifies the `sys.path` to contain the project root directory so that things like `import mysite.settings` should work everywhere in your project.

Refer to django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/faq/usage/#why-do-i-get-an-error-about-importing-django-settings-module)

Also, Python does allow modification of `sys.path`. From the Python [docs](https://A%20program%20is%20free%20to%20modify%20this%20list%20for%20its%20own%20purposes.%20Only%20strings%20and%20bytes%20should%20be%20added%20to%20sys.path;%20all%20other%20data%20types%20are%20ignored%20during%20import.)

> A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes. Only
> strings and bytes should be added to sys.path; all other data types
> are ignored during import.

If your objective is to get the directory urls.py is in, you should use the approach django uses in its settings.py file.

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint as pp

import inner.code01


pp({os.path.abspath(__file__): sys.path[:4]})
```

*code01.py* (located in *dir* called ***inner***, next to *code00.py*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint as pp


pp({os.path.abspath(__file__): sys.path[:4]})
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073104391]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> tree /a /f
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   code00.py
> |
> \---inner
>     |   code01.py
>     |
>     \---__pycache__
>             code01.cpython-39.pyc
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" inner/code01.py
> {'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q073104391\\inner\\code01.py': ['e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q073104391\\inner',
>                                                                 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils\\current',
>                                                                 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils',
>                                                                 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.09\\python39.zip']}
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> {'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q073104391\\inner\\code01.py': ['e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q073104391',
>                                                                 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils\\current',
>                                                                 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils',
>                                                                 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.09\\python39.zip']}
> {'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q073104391\\code00.py': ['e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q073104391',
>                                                          'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils\\current',
>                                                          'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils',
>                                                          'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.09\\python39.zip']}
> ```

What happens is that when running a module directly, ***Python* adds its location** (as 1<sup>st</sup> entry) **in [[Python.Docs]: sys.path](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path)** (default behavior). When importing one, this (naturally) doesn't happen.

Same thing happens in your case, when you run modules directly, their location is in *sys.path* (you could test that by launching *urls.py*).

So, there's no inconsistency on *Django* (has nothing to do with it) or *Python* side, but on the way you are dealing with modules.

If you really want *urls.py* in *sys.path* (although if this was truly necessary it would be done by *Django* automatically), add it either:

- Manually
- From *Django*'s config file